# INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have column in Athena table as time -> string

I am trying to convert to datetime as below :

```
SELECT
     "source"
   , "account"
   , CAST(time as date) Datetime
   
   FROM
     "testdata"
```

It gives me below error:

```
INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date: 2021-11-28T08:04:21Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATE_PARSE`:

```sql
SELECT source, account,
       DATE_PARSE(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ') AS Datetime
FROM testdata;
```

Comment: Will the result be in UTC timeformat ?

Comment: In SQL, dates don't really have any internal "format," but rather they are just stored as binary.  I don't know how Presto handles time zones.  You may research it.

Answer (score 10):

Your timestamp looks like it's formatted using ISO 8601, and Athena has a function for that: [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp)

```sql
SELECT
  source,
  account,
  from_iso8601_timestamp("time") AS datetime
FROM testdata
```

If you only want the date part you can cast the result of the function to date:

```sql
SELECT
  source,
  account,
  CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp("time") AS DATE) AS "date"
FROM testdata
```